# Access file and folder from Google drive from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I am trying to created an ASP.NET MVC web application to access Google drive files.

What I have created so far:

1. Enabled my API from Google developer console.
2. Created a project and its credentials for web application which gives "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs".
3. I have pasted it in my web application.

If I create a console application, it works fine, but not in the web application.
I get an authentication error.

I have followed [this link](https://www.thecodehubs.com/google-drive-integration-in-asp-net-mvc/?unapproved=880&moderation-hash=79f6612d91e807e507ee1391b5fd78dd#comment-880) but if you see in detail you will find it have client_secret.json which only work on installed app (desktop app).

Auth error is like [this attached screenshot](https://prnt.sc/uyggft)

Comment: Did you read the 5 comments at the bottom of your link?  The code is using HTTPS (Secure) so there is an TLS authentication which is probably failing.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the version of TLS that is being used.  TLS 1.0/1.1 no longer works and you must use TLS 1.2/1.3.  I suspect the command on the link that it only works on localhost is probably due to the wrong version of TLS.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng but i have also created the app with https ://localhost but the error remain same.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

According to the [Google Drive API documentation for .NET](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) the 400 error is due to a missing parameter in this case the **redirect_uri**. You have to make sure that your `credentials.json` has the following format:

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "quickstart-xxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "https://example.com"
    ],
    "javascript_origins": [
      "https://example.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

Where `"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"` is how you tell the OAuth Server that you want the code in the same page. I strongly recommend you to search for official Google Documentation. For further information about accesing Google APIs take a look into the [Google OAuth Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

### Reference

[Google Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet)

[OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: @josh-vasquez `credentials.json` that you are referring is for installed app like console or desktop app. It works fine for this **but not ** for web application or in live server.

Comment: If you included the line I mentioned it has to. When you first run your web app or console app, you have to choose between these (desktop app, web browser, Android App, etc) in your API project, then download the `credentials.json` and make sure it has the line `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` if you don't want to get the code via **redirect_uris** `http://example.com?code=CODE`. Anyway, once you get that code copy/paste it on your console (where you first ran your app), it will generate a `token.json` which is the token used everytime your application wants to access the desired API.